# Load file from classpath without InputStreams

Tags: java, file, url, io, inputstream

I have a library that cannot accept InputStreams. It only accepts Files and URLs as input to load music. Is there any way to load a file that is in my resources folder without an InputStream? Or do I just need to create a separate folder for sounds and load them using

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + path_to_file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class[Loader].getResource()` returns a URL. Use this method to get a URL pointing to your classpath resource, and pass the URL to your library.

Comment: Thank you! So for example, say I have my sound in "root/res/sound.wav" and my class is in "root/src/utitlies/Sound.java", would I need to include the full path to the wav file?